# Matlab: reading matrix from file

Tags: image, matlab, file, loops, for-loop

I have a file with images and another file called "depth" with depth maps for those images. The each depth map has exactly the same name as its image.

I have written a code to read images and then in a loop, I am trying to read the each depth map associated with the current image as follow:

```
folder = '$folder path';

imageFiles =   {'img_1', ...
                'img_2', ...
                'img_3', ...
                'img_4', ...
                'img_5'};

 img = cell(length(imageFiles),1);
 H = nan(5,5,length(imageFiles));
 D = cell(length(imageFiles),1);


for j=1:length(imageFiles)
   img{j} = load([folder imageFiles{j}]);
   H(:,:,j) = img{j}.RectOptions.RectCamIntrinsicsH;
   img{j} = uint8(img{j}.img(:,:,:,:,1:3) / 255);
   fprintf('%s\n', imageFiles{j})

   D{j} = load([folder 'depth/' imageFiles{j}]);
   D{j} = D{j};
end
```

D suppoed to be 426 x 630 but I get an error and when I check D value I get the following:

```
D =

5×1 cell array

[1×1 struct]
[1×1 struct]
[1×1 struct]
[1×1 struct]
[1×1 struct]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your depth image is a `.png` file, you should probably use `imread` instead of `load`.

Comment: @beaker the depth maps are in .mat format and not .png

Comment: Okay then, what does `D{1}` contain?

Comment: That's what you expect it to contain. What does it *actually* contain? I suspect that it is a struct with at least one named variable. If you display `D{1}`, it should show you the contents of the structure, including the variable name. If you then display `D{1}.variable_name` it should then give you the actual depth image. But since I don't have your data files I can't do that on my own. :)

Comment: @beaker thank you that solved the question, I completely forgot to add .variable_name :)

Comment: @beaker Would you mind posting this as an answer so Anna1994 can accept it?  I'll upvote it if nothing else.